# Knockout.js - Setting initial values through a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, knockout.js

I've got a rails app in which I want to setup my task object with some default values through rails and have knockout.js use those defaults for the observables.

What currently happens is the default from the rails controller is quickly replaced with a blank from the knockout.js observable command.

Here is my rails controller

```
def new
  @task = Task.new
  @task.task_date = Time.now
end
```

My knockout

```
Task = ->
  @name = ko.observable()
  @task_date = ko.observable()
```

My form

```
= f.text_field :task_date, "data-bind" => "value: name"
= f.text_field :task_date, "data-bind" => "value: task_date"
```

Do I have to pass JSON from my controller instead of using the default "render :new"?

Can I use the rails defaults at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are rendering a view and rails is writing the value to the fields in question then knockout it binding to the DOM and blanking out the fields because the  `observable` has no value.

1. render the values of your model in the page as json
2. make a round trip via ajax to get the values
3. render the values in the page markup and extract these values for your model

Options 1 & 3 are easy for the server and only require the one request for the page. Client-side #1 is simple as mapping the data to your model and binding while #3 requires code to extract from the markup (i.e. if you're putting your data in a `data-*` attribute on your elements) but could make for nicer markup, but its more work to come up with a scheme for doing your initial binding of value to models considering collections etc.

Option 2 requires two trips, one to get the html and another to get json, doubling your requests to the db also unless you add code to skip the db on the html get. Ick.

[edit]
There is also the `gon` gem that I haven't used and this screencast from RailsCasts that shows these techniques in action: http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Comment: With option 1 do you mean create a second data element on my date field like "data-initial" => @task.task_date and then read this into my observable with $("#task_task_date").data('initial') ?

Comment: updated - check out the gon gem and see the RailsCast episode 324 - it shows these techniques. They're not knockout-specific, but show how to get the model data to the client where it can be consumed by knockout.